# Cómo definir numero mayor y menor de 10 numeros ingesados en visual basic

Tags: array, vb.net, bucle-for, condiciones

tengo un problema a la hora de utilizar los arreglos, el ejercicio debe de ser resuelto utilizando las sentencias IF y FOR

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim numMayor As Decimal
    Dim numMenor As Decimal

    Private Sub btnCalcular_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalcular.Click

        Dim numeros(9) As Integer

        For i As Integer = 0 To 10

            numeros(i) = txtIngresar.Text
            txtMostrar.Text = numeros(i)

        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de lo que has intentado.

Comment: *¿Cuál es el problema?*

Comment: y vuelvo a insistir, cual es el problema? donde se ingresan los numeros? donde estas comprobando el mayor y menor? donde estas recorriendo los numeros ingresados?

Comment: Guardar números ingresados mediante el txt y guardarlos para luego mostrarlos. Ese sería el problema

Comment: Pero eso es tu ejercicio, y aca no hacemos ejercicios. Si te ayudamos con un problema o duda puntual que tuviste al resolver tu ejercicio. Por ejemplo, ahi siempre ingresas el mismo numero en todas las posiciones.. para empezar, deberias arreglar eso...

Answer (score 0):

A lo mejor lo que quieres es algo así, ya que no se te entiende la pregunta...
Si lo que quieres es recorrer un array de números que has separado por comas en el textbox, el ejercicio se resuelve así

```
Public Class Form1

Private numMayor As Integer = 0
Private numMenor As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnCalcular_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalcular.Click
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    ' Con esto Puedes convertir en array los números 
    ' que has puesto en el txtIngresar separados por la coma
    Dim numeros() As Integer = Split(txtIngresar.Text, ",")

    ' Buscar el Mayor
    For i = LBound(numeros) To UBound(numeros)
        If numeros(i) > numMayor Then
            numMayor = numero(i)
        End If 
    Next 

    ' Buscar el Menor
    For i = LBound(numeros) To UBound(numeros)
        If numeros(i) < numMenor Then
            numMenor = numeros(i)
        End If 
    Next
    
    ' Para Finalizar Vemos Cual es el Número Mayor y el Menor
    MsgBox("El Número Mayor es: " & numMayor & vbCrLf & 
           "El Número Menor es: " & numMenor )

End Sub
End Class
```